# Invisible layout on iPhone and iPad when CSS @media is applied

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, media-queries

The problem could be simulated here:
https://demo-bi.abra.eu/app/show

There should be this:

[image]

But on iPhone, or iPad there is this, but only on first load:
[image]

On the second load all items are visible correctly, like in the first image.

Every item in list is affected by this CSS style:

```
@media (min-width: 26.25rem) {
.app-main-page-layout .igate-list-sorted .igate-list-pageslist-item {
    max-width: none;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}}
```

I found out, that in case you delete the "@media" section, everything works fine and all items in list are visible:

```
.app-main-page-layout .igate-list-sorted .igate-list-pageslist-item {
        max-width: none;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
```

The interesting thing is that the style is applied with or without @media query. So it should have no impact on that, but it does.

It is happening on any iPhone, iPad in Safari or Chrome.

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couldn't recreate in chrome 'toggle device' it seems suspicious that reloading fixes the problem, maybe it doesn't relate to CSS but to JS. I will suggest changing the `float` to `flex` or `grid` anyways.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but javascript should not be the problem, because of standard wicket html server creating usage. Yes, it is very strange. Could you simulate it e.g. on iPhone? This does not appear on a desktop or android.

Comment: sorry, I don't have an iPhone. but if the @madie is redundant you should remove it. or maybe when you remove the `float` styling and change it to `flex-box` it will work better because `float` is very outdated and maybe even buggy in new versions of browsers (e.g Safari). good luck

Comment: I have used grid. Thx. :)